# Unblocked CHM file works on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: linux, chm, viewer

I downloaded a `.chm` file and found that all the content pages are displayed blank. In Windows, I selected `privacy` tab in `Properties` and clicked the `unblock` button. Now I can see the CHM file contents.

However, when I tried viewing this file using Kchmviewer in Ubuntu Lucid, it displayed the pages as blank! I can read other CHM files with out any problem.

Do I need to do something more to view the pages?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has to do anything with the blocking. The blocking system relies on filesystems with multiple streams, and happens on Windows shell (not even kernel) level. So it is simply a kchmviewer problem, and/or the CHM uses non standard html. (a CHM is basically archived html)

Note that kchmviewer can iirc switch viewer. khtmlviewer vs webkit or so. Try to switch viewer and see if that improves matters.